# python manage.py createsuperuser works on Mac, but does not work on windows

Tags: django

I have been going through the Django tutorial in the following link.   I have completed this on a Mac, however I am hitting problems on windows 10:

[djangoproject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/)

In Tutorial part 2, when it comes to creating a new superuser, it fails.

If I run the following on a Mac, I can create a new superuser.   It fails when I run a similar command on windows.

I have tried running both of the following on windows:

```
source venv/bin/activate
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

and

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
py manage.py createsuperuser
```

Package (pip list):

```
Package     Version
----------- -------
Django      2.2.6
docutils    0.15.2
pip         19.3.1
pycodestyle 2.5.0
pytz        2019.3
setuptools  41.4.0
sqlparse    0.3.0
wheel       0.33.6
```

The db.sqlite3 database is present, and as far as I can tell has a reasonable structure (there are lots of Django specific tables).

I expect to create a new superuser, but instead get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Development\Python\PYTHON---DJANGO---TUTORIAL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\password_validation.py", line 26, in get_password_validators
    klass = import_string(validator['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Development\Python\PYTHON---DJANGO---TUTORIAL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Development\Python\PYTHON---DJANGO---TUTORIAL\venv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation                '

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Development\Python\PYTHON---DJANGO---TUTORIAL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Development\Python\PYTHON---DJANGO---TUTORIAL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Development\Python\PYTHON---DJANGO---TUTORIAL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Development\Python\PYTHON---DJANGO---TUTORIAL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 61, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Development\Python\PYTHON---DJANGO---TUTORIAL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Development\Python\PYTHON---DJANGO---TUTORIAL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 132, in handle
    validate_password(password2, self.UserModel(**fake_user_data))
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Development\Python\PYTHON---DJANGO---TUTORIAL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\password_validation.py", line 44, in validate_password
    password_validators = get_default_password_validators()
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Development\Python\PYTHON---DJANGO---TUTORIAL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\password_validation.py", line 19, in get_default_password_validators
    return get_password_validators(settings.AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Development\Python\PYTHON---DJANGO---TUTORIAL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\password_validation.py", line 29, in get_password_validators
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg % validator['NAME'])
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The module in NAME could not be imported: django.contrib.auth.password_validation                .UserAttributeSimilarityValidator. Check your AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS setting.
```

Comment: try uninstalling and re-installing django (using --no-cache)

Comment: The `No module named 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation                '` bit makes me guess there are actual spaces or some other invalid characters in your settings for password validators.

Comment: Hi, I tried uninstalling Django and then re-installing it with the --no-cache argument and that did not fix the problem.

Comment: I must admit that I am not sure what django.contrib.auth.password_validation this means or how to fix it.   If anybody could help, that would be great.   Thanks

Comment: Did you copy the installation from Windows to Mac or did you do a fresh install of Django on Windows?

Comment: Hi Matthew, I wrote the Django app on a Mac and then copied it onto windows to test it.   I have a make file and requirements.txt file that I use to set everything up and as part of the process I delete the previous virtual environment and then create it from the requirements.txt file.   Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have made a copy of the repository public on GitHub.   It would be great if anybody could help me solve this problem.   Many thanks, Mark     https://github.com/MarkyMark1000/PYTHON---DJANGO---TUTORIAL

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, the [problem is in your password validation configuration](https://github.com/MarkyMark1000/PYTHON---DJANGO---TUTORIAL/blob/d0b9e10fbdd177db5cecdf3d67eb7c7e59156a0d/mysite/settings.py#L90-L107), in the way you've set up those line continuations using backslashes.

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation\
                .UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation\
                .MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation\
                .CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation\
                .NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

evaluates to

```
[
{'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation                .UserAttributeSimilarityValidator'}, 
{'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation                .MinimumLengthValidator'}, 
{'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation                .CommonPasswordValidator'}, 
{'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation                .NumericPasswordValidator'}
]
```

and there's no such module as `django/contrib/auth/password_validation                .py`.

If the same code works on macOS, then... okay, weird, could be a filename normalization thing, but still, that's the problem.

The fix, naturally, is to change that to

```py
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator'}, 
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator'}, 
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator'}, 
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator'},
]
```

or if you'd like to have those line continuations,

```py
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation."
        "UserAttributeSimilarityValidator"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation."
        "MinimumLengthValidator"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation."
        "CommonPasswordValidator"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation."
        "NumericPasswordValidator"
    },
]
```

– that is, string literals back to back, implicitly concatenating them – is also valid, even if, in my opinion, less readable.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much.   I added the line continuation characters because pycodestyle kept raising issues saying that the line was too long, so I have used your second suggestion.   I'm new to Django, so once again, thank you so much for your help.